# Rubyで濁点を分離したい

Tags: ruby

Rubyでひらがなから濁点を分離したいと考えていますがどのような実装が考えられるか教えていただけませんでしょうか？

#### 例

```
a = remove_dakuten('だ')
puts a
\# た゛
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicodeっぽく処理をするのであれば、NFD正規化で濁点を分離できます。

```
"だ".unicode_normalize(:nfd) #=> 「た」+U+3099
```

ただし、この分離された濁点文字(U+3099)は前の文字と結合するための特殊な文字なので、通常の濁点文字(U+309B)にしたい場合は次のように変換すればいいと思います。

```
"だ".unicode_normalize(:nfd).tr("\u3099", "\u309b") #=> 「た」+「゛」
```

半濁点も同様にするにはこんな感じで。

```
"ぱ".unicode_normalize(:nfd).tr("\u3099\u309a", "\u309b\u309c") #=> 「は」+「゜」
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらでバッチリでした！

Answer (score 2):

文字コードの表で一つ前の文字を参照するというのはどうでしょうか。

```
def remove_dakuten(char)
    (char.ord - 1).chr('UTF-8')
end

puts remove_dakuten('だ')
```

#### 参考

- ord, chrメソッドについて:  http://chuckwebtips.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/03/000000
- UTF-8ひらがなカタカナ表:  http://aspiration.sakura.ne.jp/wiki/index.php?develop%2FUTF-8%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A%E8%A1%A8

Comment: リンク先がきれてしまった際に回答を損うことが無いようにサンプルコード自体も質問文に含めてください。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Myaku ご指摘有難うございます。修正いたしました。

Comment: なるほどこの発想はありませんでした！ありがとうございます！